# load testing with Arquillian? (with maybe another tools)

Tags: load-testing, jboss-arquillian

I'm using Arquillian and I need to do load test, something like running the same test with 50 threads in parallel.
I tried with ContiPerf 2 and it didn't work. It is not possible.

So, do you recommend me any tool for doing the load test with Arquillian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't think I would *Arquillian* for that. AFAIK there is no extensions available at the moment for load testing. Personally I made good experiences with *JMeter*, but it depends of course how you set things up.

Comment: The problem is that the application uses Flex, so we don't have servlets like in the common web applications. This makes the JMeter testing more difficult.

Comment: More difficult, but possible. You can run for example run JUnit tests and even integrate the performance tests into a maven build via the JMeter maven plugin.

Comment: At the end I created an Integration test without Arquillian but with Contiperf. This covers my needs. JMeter is always an option but we had a lot of problems, so I was looking for another solution. Thank you for your help.